# How to get only i column from relation laravel 5

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 2 model (Event & Budgeting) in relation with eloquent laravel,

## Model Event Realation With Budgeting

```
public function budgeting()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Budgeting', 'id_event', 'id');
}
```

## I want to get only one column 'total' from budgeting

this code controller show nothing from budgeting

```
public function data()
{
  $listdata = Event::orderBy('id', 'desc')->with(array('budgeting'=>function($query){
    $query->select('total','item');
    }))->get();

  return $listdata;
}
```

Comment: does `Event::orderBy('id', 'desc')->with('budgeting')->get()` returns any budgeting data ?

Comment: yes this is return all data from Budgeting Model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it's not working is because you need to also select the `id_event` in order for Eloquent to build the relationship. Without the `id_event`, Eloquent does not know which `Budgeting` belongs to which `Event`.

General rule to follow: Whenever you alter the select query and you are building a relationship, you have to select the relationship ids at a minimum.

Change your query like this, and it should work.

```
$listdata = Event::orderBy('id', 'desc')->with(array('budgeting'=>function($query){
    $query->select(`id_event`, 'total','item');
}))->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make another relation in you event model to get only the specific column

```
public function totalBudgeting()
{
     return $this->hasMany('App\Budgeting', 'id_event', 'id')->select(['total','item']);
}
```